# Using Span<> and Memory<> to read UTF8 from a socket

Tags: c#, console, stream, .net-core

I am experimenting with `Span<>` and `Memory<>` and checking how to use it for example for reading UTF8 text from a `NetworkStream` using [`Read(Span<Byte>)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.read?view=netcore-2.1#System_IO_Stream_Read_System_Span_System_Byte__). I created a fake method that simulates the byte read, and although this code works for the test, I am wondering if this is the right way of doing the most with these new structures in terms of efficiency and memory.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Memory<byte> byteMemory = new byte[3];
    Memory<char> charMemory = new char[1024];

    var byteMemoryPos = 0;
    var byteMemoryReaded = 0;
    var charMemoryPos = 0;
    var readed = -1;

    var decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();

    do
    {
        // pass the sliced part of the memory where I want to write as span
        readed = FakeNetworkStreamRead(byteMemory.Slice(byteMemoryPos + byteMemoryReaded).Span);
        Console.WriteLine($"Readed {readed} bytes");

        byteMemoryReaded += readed;

        // pass the sliced part of the memory I want to parse, and the part 
        // of the char buffer where I want to write
        decoder.Convert(byteMemory.Slice(byteMemoryPos, byteMemoryReaded).Span,
                        charMemory.Slice(charMemoryPos).Span,
                        false, out int bytesUsed, out int charsUsed, out bool completed);

        // update offsets and counts
        byteMemoryPos -= bytesUsed;
        charMemoryPos += charsUsed;
        byteMemoryReaded -= bytesUsed;

        // reset offset if nothing to read
        if (byteMemoryReaded == 0)
            byteMemoryPos = 0;
    }
    while (readed != 0);

    Console.WriteLine(new string(charMemory.Slice(0, charMemoryPos).Span));
}

static int _position = 0;
static byte[] _data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hi this is test!!");

/// <summary>
/// Pretends to be NetworkStream.Read, that only manages to read 5 bytes each time
/// </summary>
/// <param name="span"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
static int FakeNetworkStreamRead(Span<byte> span)
{
    var pending = Math.Min(_data.Length - _position, span.Length);
    pending = Math.Min(pending, 5);
    for (int i = _position, j = 0; i < _position + pending; j++, i++)
    {
        span[j] = _data[i];
    }
    _position += pending;
    return pending;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experience with `Span<T>` or `Memory<T>` so the following is just some general considerations on coding etc.

---

In `FakeNetworkStreamRead(...)`: why have a internal limit of 5 bytes? Why not let the length of the `Span<T>` argument determine the maximum bytes to read?

---

Why are you using a `Memory<T>` as buffer, when reading from the stream?:

```
Memory<byte> byteMemory = new byte[3];
```

Why not just a Span, because you only use it as a such and not holding or collecting any data in it:

```
Span<byte> byteSpan = new byte[3];
```

---

IMO you should change the `do {} while(...)` loop to a `while (...)` loop, because, if the stream is empty you do a "lot" of work in the first round trip for no reason:

```
  int read = 0;

  while ((read = FakeNetworkStreamRead(byteSpan)) > 0)
  {
    ...
  }
```

---

With the above in mind I've tried to refactor your code to:

```
static int FakeNetworkStreamRead(Span<byte> span)
{
  int stop = Math.Min(_position + span.Length, _data.Length);
  int i = 0;

  for (; _position < stop; i++, _position++)
  {
    span[i] = _data[_position];
  }

  return i;
}



static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Span<byte> byteSpan = new byte[3];
  Memory<char> charMemory = new char[1024];

  var charMemoryPos = 0;
  var decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
  int read = 0;

  while ((read = FakeNetworkStreamRead(byteSpan)) > 0)
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"Read {read} bytes");

    // pass the sliced part of the memory I want to parse, and the part 
    // of the char buffer where I want to write
    decoder.Convert(byteSpan.Slice(0, read),
                    charMemory.Slice(charMemoryPos).Span,
                    false, out int bytesUsed, out int charsUsed, out bool completed);

    // update offsets and counts
    charMemoryPos += charsUsed;
  }

  Console.WriteLine(new string(charMemory.Slice(0, charMemoryPos).Span));
}
```

---

In order to flush the `decoder` state, the `do {} while(...)` loop is useful anyway:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  int bufferLength = 3;
  Span<byte> byteSpan = new byte[bufferLength];
  Memory<char> charMemory = new char[1024];

  var charMemoryPos = 0;
  var decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
  int read = 0;

  do 
  {
    read = FakeNetworkStreamRead(byteSpan);

    decoder.Convert(byteSpan.Slice(0, read),
                    charMemory.Slice(charMemoryPos).Span,
                    read == 0, out int bytesUsed, out int charsUsed, out bool completed);

    Console.WriteLine($"Read {read} bytes -> Used: {bytesUsed} -> Completed: {completed} -> CharUsed: {charsUsed} -> {decoder.FallbackBuffer.Remaining}");

    charMemoryPos += charsUsed;
  } while (read > 0) ;

  Console.WriteLine(new string(charMemory.Slice(0, charMemoryPos).Span);
}
```

Here the `read == 0` argument to `decoder.Convert(...)` becomes true at the end of the stream, which will flush the state and clears the internal buffer of `decoder`

Comment: Hi, thanks for that! The limits are artificial for the sake of the test. The UTF8 decoder is not always able to transform all the bytes into chars, since some chars have up to 4 bytes, and maybe not all are present in the buffer, that is why `bytesUsed` is very important.

Comment: @vtortola: You are certainly right. I was blundering, and my answer isn't that good at all.

Comment: @vtortola: And then again, I think the decoder maintains the state internally, so I think your math is redundant when it comes to `byteMemoryPos` and `byteMemoryReaded`

Comment: You are actually right. That out var is useful for when the target char array cannot hold all the input array, which is not the case. Thanks!